# sqfentity_gen, sqfentity orm in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, sqlite, dart, local-storage

While using the sqfentity and sqfentity_gen an error occurs.

error : **SQFENTITIY ERROR: Table named [primary] could not create. Message: DatabaseException(near "primary": syntax error: , while compiling: Create table primary (id integer primary key, name text, email text, mobile integer, countryCode text, shortName text, gender integer DEFAULT '0', password text, isDeleted numeric NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)) sql 'Create table primary (id integer primary key, name text, email text, mobile integer, countryCode text, shortName text, gender integer DEFAULT '0', password text, isDeleted numeric NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)' args []**

code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sqfentity/sqfentity.dart';
import 'package:sqfentity_gen/sqfentity_gen.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
part 'model.g.dart';

// This is where we define our tables:
const SqfEntityTable tablePrimaryInfo = SqfEntityTable(
    tableName: 'primary',
    primaryKeyName: 'id',
    primaryKeyType: PrimaryKeyType.integer_auto_incremental,
    useSoftDeleting: true,
    modelName: null,
    fields: [
      SqfEntityField('name', DbType.text, defaultValue: null),
      SqfEntityField('email', DbType.text),
      SqfEntityField('mobile', DbType.integer),
      SqfEntityField('countryCode', DbType.text),
      SqfEntityField('shortName', DbType.text),
      SqfEntityField('gender', DbType.integer, defaultValue: 0),
      SqfEntityField('password', DbType.text)
    ]);

const seqIdentity = SqfEntitySequence(
  sequenceName: 'identity',
);

const SqfEntityTable secondaryPrimaryInfo = SqfEntityTable(
    tableName: 'secondary',
    primaryKeyName: 'id',
    primaryKeyType: PrimaryKeyType.integer_auto_incremental,
    useSoftDeleting: true,
    modelName: null,
    fields: [
      SqfEntityField('dob', DbType.text),
      SqfEntityField('age', DbType.text),
      SqfEntityField('height', DbType.integer),
      SqfEntityField('complexion', DbType.integer),
      SqfEntityField('bodyType', DbType.text),
      SqfEntityField('physicalStatus', DbType.text),
      SqfEntityField('differentlyAbledCat', DbType.integer),
      SqfEntityField('specifyDifferentlyAbled', DbType.integer),
      SqfEntityField('maritalStatus', DbType.text),
      SqfEntityField('familyStatus', DbType.text),
      SqfEntityField('denomination', DbType.integer),
      SqfEntityField('diocese', DbType.integer),
      SqfEntityField('dioceseName', DbType.text),
      SqfEntityField('parishName', DbType.integer),
    ]);

// This is where we define our database:
@SqfEntityBuilder(myDbModel)
const myDbModel = SqfEntityModel(
  modelName: 'MyAppDatabaseModel',
  databaseName: 'my-db.db',
  sequences: [seqIdentity],
  databaseTables: [tablePrimaryInfo, secondaryPrimaryInfo], //if you will be adding new tables, do not forget to put them here
);
```

data loading function :

```
loadData() async {
    List<Primary> primaryInfo = [];
    primaryInfo = await Primary().select().toList();
    return primaryInfo;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename
tableName: 'primary', to
any other name like
'tableName: 'primaryInfo','

Comment: This works fine, Brilliant work bro...